# Highchart reloading upon call issue - javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I'm trying to update my piechart LIVE without redrawing the piechart, any advice?

this is the function that is being called

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    piecharts(i, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    i++;
 },5000);

function piecharts(sector0Data, sector1Data, sector2Data, sector3Data, sector4Data, sector5Data)
{
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: false,
                alpha: 45,
                beta: 0
            }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Number of person in each sector'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            depth: 35,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y} ', //change percentage to y for decimal value
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{ 
        name: 'Avg number of person in this sector over the total of ',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Sector0',
            y: sector0Data
        },{
            name: 'Sector1',
            y: sector1Data
        },{
            name: 'Sector2',
            y: sector2Data
        },{
            name: 'Sector3',
            y: sector3Data
        },{
            name: 'Sector4',
            y: sector4Data
        }, {
            name: 'Sector5',
            y: sector5Data
        }]
    }]
});
}
```

For every 5 second, my i will increase by 1 and my pie-chart will be drawn, this works fine but it kept redrawing my chart. any advice? thanks. also, i'm using v4.1.8 of highchart

Comment: You have a typo in your function's name (piechart or piecharts ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) method for this. Init your chart on the DOM ready event and just call a function in order to update data :

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9apr0vog/)**

```
function updatePiechart(sector0Data, sector1Data, sector2Data, sector3Data, sector4Data, sector5Data)
{
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.series[0].update({
        data: [{
              name: 'Sector0',
              y: sector0Data
          },{
              name: 'Sector1',
              y: sector1Data
          },{
              name: 'Sector2',
              y: sector2Data
          },{
              name: 'Sector3',
              y: sector3Data
          },{
              name: 'Sector4',
              y: sector4Data
          }, {
              name: 'Sector5',
              y: sector5Data
       }]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the re-render is that you create a new chart every five seconds instead of updating its data.

You need to call the [update method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) for your *y point* on your chart series data:

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update(y);
```

Here is a simple example on how to update the data: [Update pie data jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/point-update-pie/)

Or have a look at the [documentation for live data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data)